# Print static SWF on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, printing, flash, actionscript-2

I've been trying really hard on this with no results, hope someone could help me out.

What I have is an HTML page with a ActionScript2 SWF object embedded. The SWF is a static sprite that gets dynamic text from the javascript. So basically looks like an image.

I want to print out the whole page HTML + SWF included, but as expected on the possition of the SWF object appears a blank square.

I print the page using javascript `window.print()`;

Is there anyway to take a snapshot of the SWF or render it like an image? to show it on the print preview and on the printed document?
The size of the flash object is 600x381px;

Thank you!

Comment: Is the page online yet? If so, what is its URL?

Comment: the page is online, but unfortunately is not public access. Really sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys、but I finally came up with a solution.

Thanks for having a look anyways.

What I first did is to convert the flash file from ActionScript2 to ActionScript3 to be able to use the as3corelib of Mike Chambers https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib. 
From this library I used the JGPEncoder as seen below

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.display.JPEGEncoderOptions;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

function snapShot(){

    var imgBM:Bitmap;
    var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    myBitmapData.draw(stage);
    imgBM=new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
    addChild(imgBM);

    var imgBA:ByteArray;
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(90);
     //-------Send image to php

    imgBA = jpgEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);

    var sendHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');

var sendReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("parseimg.php");
    sendReq.requestHeaders.push(sendHeader);
    sendReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sendReq.data = imgBA;

    var sendLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    sendLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageSentHandler);
    sendLoader.load(sendReq);
}

var imagePath:String;

function imageSentHandler(event:Event):void {
    var dataStr:String = event.currentTarget.data.toString();
    var resultVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    resultVars.decode(dataStr);

    imagePath = "http://" + resultVars.base + resultVars.filename;
}
```

The next step was to create the php that receives the ByteArray and creates the image file on the server.

```
<?php

if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
    $filename = "your_image_name.jpg";
    $fp = fopen( $filename,"wb");
    fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
    fclose( $fp );

    echo "filename=".$filename."&base=".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); } ?>
```

Finally and with the image already in a folder on the server, I just had to hide the Embedded flash object using CSS, and show up the image instead.

I got this using jquery on document.ready

```
var d = new Date();
setTimeout(function(){
        $("#imgflash").attr("src", "your_image_name.jpg?"+d.getTime());
         setTimeout("window.print();", 200);
        },1000);
```

As I'm pretty new on ActionScript and Flash, any improvements on this code are kindly accepted.